# How to use 'includeexpr' with relative paths?

Tags: vimrc, include

Imagine there is a file `src/main.js` with import like this:

```
import { A } from '_components/A';
```

And `_components/A` in turn has

```
export { A } from './B';
```

I configured `includeexpr` to expand `_` to `src` so `_components/A` is transformed to `src/components/A`. Also since vim doesn't find relative filenames(starting with `./`) in path this function tries to make such paths absolute using path to the file loaded in current buffer:

```
let resolved_path = expand('%:p:.:h') . a:path[1:-1]
```

Then somewhere in the `main.js` I want to list all definitions of `A` by pressing [D over it.
Vim doesn't find `_components/A` in `path` so it calls function that I defined for `includeexpr` and successfully gets `src/components/A`.

The problem occurs when vim encounters reexport of `A` from `src/components/A/B`. In this case `includeexpr` resolves `./B` to `src/B` not to `src/components/A/B`

Is there a way to get correct filename? What am I doing wrong?

Some of my vim settings:

```
set path=.,,src
let &l:include = 'from\|require'
let &l:includeexpr = "ResolvePath(v:fname)"

function! ResolvePath(path) abort
  let is_relative = match(a:path, '^\.\/') == 0

  let resolved_path = fnameescape(substitute(a:path, '^\zs[\~_]\ze\a', 'src/', ''))

  if is_relative
    let resolved_path = expand('%:p:.:h') . a:path[1:-1]
  endif

  if isdirectory(resolved_path)
    return get(systemlist('find ' . resolved_path . ' -type f -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*/index.[jt]sx?"'), 0, resolved_path)
  endif

  return resolved_path
endfunction
```

File structure:

```
.
└── src
    ├── components
    │   └── A
    │       ├── B
    │       │   └── index.js
    │       └── index.js
    └── main.js
```

Comment: It would be helpfully if you could provide your configuration of `includeexpr` and maybe à simplified version of the file structure.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thank you for the comment. updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of detail missing from your question, like your `:help 'path'`, your `:help 'include'`, your `:help 'includeexpr'`, etc. but also a lot missing in Vim itself. Let's see what we can do.

This is your file structure as I understand it:

```
.
├── main.js
└── src
    └── components
        ├── A.js
        └── B.js
```

Out of the box, Vim knows how to find "defines" in a JavaScript file but it doesn't know how to find "includes". That is because, when I updated the default ftplugin for JavaScript a couple years ago, a working `&include` was not part of the update. My reasoning was that, while it is relatively easy to come up with a working one, writing a working `&includeexpr` is a lot more involved and I felt that having one without the other didn't make much sense.

The final nail in the coffin is the long standing issue with Vim itself that you can't have both a `&define` and an `&include` match on the same line, which is essentially the scenario for:

```
export { A } from './B';
```

where you import and export `A` in one statement. The default `&define` as I wrote it doesn't support that notation because it simply can't work.

So, without any configuration, Vim is incapable of doing *anything* with the `import` line in `main.js` or the `export` line in `A.js`.

Bummer.

Now, here is the `&include` I've had in my config for many years, which would have been part of that update:

```
" in after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
setlocal include=^\\s*[^\/]\\+\\(from\\\|require(\\)\\s*['\"]\\ze
```

If we open `main.js` in a clean Vim and set the option globally:

```
$ vim --clean main.js
:set include=^\\s*[^\/]\\+\\(from\\\|require(\\)\\s*['\"]\\ze
```

we can check with `:help :checkpath` that the include is found but that the file is not, which is not surprising given the provided path:

```
:checkpath
--- Included files not found in path ---
_components/A
```

The include is also found in `A.js`:

```
--- Included files in path ---
/Users/romainl/Desktop/test/src/components/./B.js
```

Now, that we can find includes, we must deal with that funky file name in `main.js`. `:help 'suffixesadd'` is correctly set out of the box so Vim will find `A.js` if we give it `A`, but the `_` alias is weird and non-standard. There are two ways to deal with it.

1. Add `src` to your `&path` and get rid of the `_` in the filename:

   ```
   :set path+=src
   :set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^_','','')
   :checkpath!
   --- Included files in path ---
   src/components/A.js
   src/components/A.js -->
     src/components/./B.js
   ```

   This is for the simplest case. In reality you would have to collect all the current aliases in a list and do that for each of them.
2. Substitute the `_` in the filename with the corresponding path.

   ```
   :set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^_','src/','')
   :checkpath!
   --- Included files in path ---
   src/components/A.js
   src/components/A.js -->
     src/components/./B.js
   ```

   Again, this is for the simplest case.

At this point, you should be able to do `[D` on `A` in `main.js` and get:

[image: victory]

--- EDIT ---

So, now that we have your exact file structure, the extra `index.js` adds a bit of complexity because `A` and `B` are considered by Vim as legitimate targets and their `index.js` is never searched.

The fix is to add `/index.js` (or `/index`, thanks to `&suffixesadd`) to the final file name. If you are confident that there will *always* be an `index.js`, then it is a simple concatenation or substitution. If you are not (and you shouldn't, IMO), then it will probably require the use of `:help glob()` to match either `A.js` or `A/index.js` given `A`.

Something like:

```
glob(substitute('_components/A','^_','src/','')..'/{index.js,}')
```

which, in this case, should return:

```
src/components/A/index.js
src/components/A
```

with the first one being the most likely candidate.

Comment: thank you for your answer. seems like I updated the question while you were writing the answer. I provided some additional information as VivianDeSmedt proposed to do.

Comment: Yeah, apparently. But see my edit, it doesn't really change things.

Comment: but how are you going to let vim know that the path that should be used for substitution is `_components/A/B`? When `includeexpr` gets './B' as `v:fname` vim doesn't know the context.

Comment: I made it work but I don't understand what was wrong with my setup since it looks like it does the same thing. I will explore and tell where was the mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it is `find` inside my `ResolvePath` function not vim doesn't know the context. It tries to find `.*/index.[jt]sx?` in `./B` which is obviously wrong.

But unfortunately glob also doesn't know about the context and returns empty list if used with `v:fname`.

So, apparently the real question is "How to get name of the file that is being searched for includes inside `includeexpr`?"

Comment: What "context" exactly? Neither `./B` nor `./B/index.js` need any context because they are relative to the current file. ""How to get name of the file that is being searched for includes inside `includeexpr`?" The name of the file that is searched is what you *return* with `includeexpr`. It is not known in `includeexpr` because the purpose of `includeexpr` is precisely to build it.

Comment: "Neither ./B nor ./B/index.js need any context because they are relative to the current file." So I want to know what the current file is so I can check whether `currentFile/./B/index.js` exists or not. Then I will be able to return `currentFile/.B/index.js` or, if it doesn't exist, `./B` without any modification.

Comment: That information is not available in `includeexpr`.

Comment: Oh, it is unfortunate. Thank you!

Comment: hello again, romainl! I have one more question regarding your answer)
what do you suggest to assign the result of `glob()` to? `includeexpr`? it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You would use `glob()` or whatever works for you inside a function `MyIncludeFunction()` that you assign to `includeexpr`.